# Google Maps Toggling Overlays With Checkbox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck. I can't get my checkbox functional. I would like to toggle two layers with a checkbox. The two layers should be on when loaded (check box checked) and then turned off when unchecked. Simple, I know, but I can't get it functional despite looking at lots of working examples and checking all the posts. Most of the stuff I found were how it worked with KML and fusion tables. I have something working kinda that works for a button but this doesn't work well for check boxes.

Here is the code for the drop down box with the check boxes.

```
tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
                return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime();
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            opacity:0.50,
            name : 'NEXRAD',
            isPng: true
        });


       goes = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
                return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/goes-ir-4km-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime();
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            opacity:0.50,
            name : 'GOES NA Vis',
            isPng: true
        });

        //create the check box items
        var radarOptions = {
                gmap: map,
                title: "This allows for selection/toggling on/off Radar layer",
                id: "radarCheck",
                label: "Radar",
                action: function(){
                if (map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                  map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",tileNEX);
                }
                else {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }

            }
}

        var check1 = new checkBox(radarOptions);

        var radarAnimate = {
                gmap: map,
                title: "This allows for selection/toggling on/off Animated Radar",
                id: "radarAnimate",
                label: "Animate Radar",
                action: function(){
                    alert('Function is coming soon');
                }
        }
        var check2 = new checkBox(radarAnimate);

        var satOptions = {
                gmap: map,
                title: "This allows for selection/toggling on/off Satelite layer",
                id: "satCheck",
                label: "Satellite",
                action: function(){
                if (map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                  map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",goes);
                }
                else {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }

            }
}
        var check3 = new checkBox(satOptions);

        //create the input box items

        //possibly add a separator between controls
        var sep = new separator();

        //put them all together to create the drop down
        var ddDivOptions = {
            items: [sep, check1, check2, check3],
            id: "myddOptsDiv"
        }
        //alert(ddDivOptions.items[1]);
        var dropDownDiv = new dropDownOptionsDiv(ddDivOptions);

        var dropDownOptions = {
                gmap: map,
                name: 'Options',
                id: 'ddControl',
                title: 'A custom drop down select with mixed elements',
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                dropDown: dropDownDiv
        }

        var dropDown1 = new dropDownControl(dropDownOptions);
```

[FULL CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/radar.js)

[LINK TO MAP](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgr3radar.php)

Comment: Still looking for suggestions if anyone has one. I still haven't been able to find a working solution for my situation.

Comment: Hi,
The problem is it still relevant ?

When loading the page which have the map, i've got some javascript errors...

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getPrefs' of undefined wundermap.min.js:8969
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'removeOverlays'

Comment: @SebP sorry I thought I had deleted this as I have taken a different approach and found another source to generate a different layer. The current question is found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005537/goolge-maps-toggle-button