# Google Maps toggle button

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been struggling with this all day. I have made new buttons to actually go on my map that match the Google Maps buttons sit on the map better. I have been trying to get them to work with the current buttons above the map so I can remove those but I can't seem to get them to work. What am I missing.

Here is a link to the page so you can see. The buttons above the map work and I am going to remove them. The buttons on the map don't work which I am trying to get to work.

[DEMO LINK](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgr3radar.php)

Here is the code. The var radarButton and var satButton is the new ones. The ones below that is to the current buttons.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var mapTypeId = wundermap.getMapTypeId("hyb");
        var googlemap = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.782878, -96.609862),
              panControl: false,
              zoom: 6,
              mapTypeId: mapTypeId,
              mapTypeControl: true,
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },
    });

    var radarOptions = {
        gmap: googlemap,
        name: 'Radar',
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
        action: function(){
                if (wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                  wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                  wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",Radar);
                }
                else {
                    wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }

            }
}
var radarButton = new buttonControl(radarOptions);

var satOptions = {
        gmap: googlemap,
        name: 'Satellite',
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
        action: function(){
                if (wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                  wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                  wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1",Satellite);
                }
                else {
                    wundermap.map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }

            }
}
var satButton = new buttonControl(satOptions);

        wundermap.setOptions({
            map: googlemap,
            refreshPeriod: 60000,
            units: "english",
            debug: 0,
            source: "wxmap",
            StreetsOverlay: true,
            layers: [
            {
            layer: "Radar",
            active: "on",
            opacity: 70,
            type: "N0R",
            type2: "",
            animation: {
            num: 6,
            max: 10,
            delay: 25
            },
            stormtracks: "off",
            smooth: "on",
            subdomain: "radblast-aws"
            },
            {
            layer: "Satellite",
            defaultUI: 0,
            opacity: "85",
            source: "",
            active: "off",
            animation: {
            num: 1,
            max: 8,
            delay: 25
            }
            },
            ],

        });
        wundermap.initialize();
    });
```

Here is the link to the code for the actual layer. The code is to long to post but the overlay is called Radar.

[RADAR CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/imap/wundermap.min.js)

Comment: Your page throws javasacript errors when the buttons are pressed.. probably a good place to start looking.

Comment: Yes, because they are not properly defined which is what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

The place to start is the JavaScript console. The error messages there tell you what the problems are.

First, when the page is loaded you have an error on line 286 of wxgr3radar.php:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

Where is your `initialize()` function defined? I don't see it in your code.

Then, when I click the Satellite button it stops on line 41 of imap.js because `map.overlayMapTypes` is undefined:

```
if (map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
```

Here you're expecting `map` to be a Maps API object, but `map` is not what you think it is. Look at it in the debugger. It's a DOM element, not a Maps API map. Your Maps API map is in a variable called `googlemap`, which you create in line 3 of imap.js.

Comment: Yes, it's undefined because I am not sure how it needs to be defined. I have tried everything. When you click on one of the top map buttons then click one of the buttons on the map all it does is bring the layer to the front.

Comment: I still get the `initialize()` error, a few seconds after I reload the page. It looks like you've already done all your initialization by then anyway. Is this just a spurious error? Continuing past that, if I then click the Radar button nothing happens, but if I click the Radar button again, it stops on line 25 of imap.js because the symbol `Radar` is not defined. Are you doing this kind of debugging? Since you didn't mention it, open the [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) in Chrome and start fixing these bugs it shows you.

Comment: The initialize() is done at the end of the code above and is applied wxgr3radar.php. I understand I am getting errors. That is what I am trying to get help with because I am not sure what variable needs to be defined to the button. I have tried everything. That is what it is showing define errors. The radar and Satellite code is in this URL which I had included above. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/imap/wundermap.min.js Its defined as Radar and Satellite.

Comment: So fix every error, one at a time. Fix the `initialize()` error first, since it happens every time you load the page. Then fix the undefined symbol `Radar` on line 25. I looked at `wundermap.min.js` and it doesn't define a symbol called `Radar` anywhere that I can see. Do you see it? It *does* define `wundermap.layers.Radar`. Is that what you were supposed to use instead of `Radar`? I don't know the code enough to tell you.

Comment: "Then fix the undefined symbol Radar on line 25." That is what I am trying to get help with. I am having trouble defining the layer to the buttons. I am not concerned with the initialize() error right now. It's unrelated otherwise the other buttons wouldn't work.

Comment: It looks like you're making progress. One problem is `googlemap` being undefined in your other functions. Take out the `var` in line 3 and add `var googlemap;` at the top of the file, before the `jQuery(ready)` call. Also `rad` is undefined in line 25. Keep at it and fix those bugs, you'll get there!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am aware rad is undefined. That is what I am needing help with. I am not sure what var I need to use for the buttons. I have been working on this for 18 hrs straight and doing things I have already done before and tried everything. All the buttons do is bring the layer to the front when you click on one. That's why I am asking for some assistance because I am not sure how to fix this.